# OpenSSH: hacked before set up?

Tags: 14.04, server, ssh, security

Today I tried setting up OpenSSH on my computer with the hope of being able to connect to it from a different computer at work. This was my first time attempting to use open-ssh.

I did the following steps:

- `sudo apt-get install openssh-server`
- modified `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

  - changed port from 22 to a number above 2000
  - changed PermitRootLogin to **no**
  - changed PasswordAuthentication to **no**
- did `/etc/init.d/ssh restart`

I basically tried to follow all of the security rules that were established in online documentation. I then fooled around a bit trying to set up port forwarding on the router.

I assumed that since I had not generated any keys or set up any passwords explicitly, nobody could access the server that I suppose was actually running.

My question, basically, is that I've now become concerned by a few factors: my Internet seems slower, and I've had a few applications crash unexpectedly. It seems like all of a sudden my computer has become less dependable and my automatic thought has been to check my assumption that an open-ssh server is not accessible if its keys have not been generated and no password has been set.

My question then, is what is the state of the open-ssh server when it is restarted for the first time? Is there any way that it can be accessed by malicious people on the outside? Since I didn't get to the point of setting passwords or certificates up (because I got scared), at what point does the open-ssh server become a liabilty (i.e. hackable)?

I sort of can't imagine that the server is instantly accessible with some sort of default password: that would be very easy to take advantage of, right? At the same time, though, I'm worried because this is all very new to me.

Some things I see in `/var/log/auth.log` that worried me:

- messages from `polkitd(authority=local)` saying something about an Unregistered Authentication Agent
- repeated attempts to access `/lib/security/pam_kwallet.so`
- message that `/tmp/.X11-unix/X0` has been linked to `/run/user/112/X11-display` (who is user 112?)

I have looked each of these up and it seems they can be explained away but at the same time, a computer without this attempt at setting up openssh has decidely fewer weird messages like this.

hoping someone can comfort me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly doubt think you were hacked. Maybe some automated bot TRIED doing something, but I doubt that even happened..

If you disabled Password Auth and did not have a public key set up, there is very very little chance of anything even possibly happening.

In answer to your `auth.log` queries:

1. That is just PAM complaining about something. Usually just a programming error or a bad dependency. Missing SSH certs maybe? (**Nothing to worry about**)
2. Pretty much the same thing as #1. I assume someone (`sshd`) was trying to find certificates and didn't find them. Certs are generally stored in things called "wallets". (**Nothing to worry about**)
3. User 112 is the LightDM user. It is completely normal for it to be talking to the Xserver. (**Nothing to worry about**)

### [image]

Regarding instability and network speed, you just enabled a server. It will definitely be slower. Even if nothing is happening. The increase in program crashing is also probably related.  More resources are being used on your computer now. Maybe there are a few config issues.

---

Also, I've dealt with hackers. If they got in looking for *sensitive* documents and didn't find them, they'll often troll. They'll delete random files. They'll wipe hard drives. They'll leave your system a broken mess. I think you're safe.

Comment: I'll get more info for you in a sec. I need to start my testing VM.

Comment: Thanks so much. So basically you're saying that until I've generated these public/private keys, the chances of getting hacked are more or less the chances of a hacker perfectly guessing a 600-plus character key right away?

Comment: @ttheb A lot less. They need your public key, your IP address, a valid username, and a couple of other things.