# Computer hacked? VNC server request

Tags: xubuntu

I am a new user since April. I run 12.04 LTS and install all security updates. That is, until API to write one's own vnc server showed up as a secjurity upgrade. It sounds suspicious. I deselected it. About 2 weeks ago, my computer really got slow. The last time it connected to the internet, it downloaded 388MB and uploaded 256MB of I don't know what. It was not doing anything I had authorized.
Bash is updated to 4.2-2ubuntu2.6.
Help!

Comment: Is there anything in your log? Do you use third-party repos?

Answer (score 0):

First off, your computer was not hacked. [You would know if it was hacked, trust me](https://askubuntu.com/questions/518219/openssh-hacked-before-set-up/518223#518223).

At the very worst, some bot was snooping around and failed to do something.

Do note that random uploading/downloading is very common and many services/browsers/softwares do it. I recommend not getting worried.

However, you should add some security methods. I recommend the following:

- Keep only the default repos and necessary third party repos. This'll cut down on the chances of a "security update" being a virus update.
- Perform all security updates you can
- ***VNC is insecure by itself.*** Secure it by using a SSH tunnel. [Instructions](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/research/dtg/attarchive/vnc/sshvnc.html) [are](http://www.science.smith.edu/~ejensen/vncssh.html) [available](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/tunneling-vnc-connections-over-ssh-howto.html) [all](http://crl.ucsd.edu/handbook/vnc/) [over](http://ucdirc.ucdavis.edu/computing/vnc_ssh_tunnel.php) [the](http://martybugs.net/smoothwall/puttyvnc.cgi) [web](https://support.cs.wwu.edu/index.php/VNC_and_tunneling_through_SSH).